# Compare frequency counts between two groups with 300 observances(variables)

Tags: r, count-data, frequency

I have a dataset with observations of counts (I've also calculated proportions of the total) between two groups. These observations are essentially on the presence of material types. I'm trying to figure out which material might be statistically over/under represented in one dataset based on using the other dataset as a "standard".

```
Material Type | Data set 1 | Data set 2
type 1        |      534   |     22
type 2        |      0     |     25
type 3        |     2276   |    9875
type 300      |       400  |     137
```

The dataset is set up as above with two columns and about 300 rows of observations.

I've run correlation analysis on this in R (cor), but only get 1 and -1 correlations. I've also run this as a chi-square (chisq.test) but the observation counts are so high that I'm guaranteed to have a ridiculously low p. I'd also like to see this broken down on a row by row analysis so I can see which types are over/under represented.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. Since you are not measuring each data set against standard but one against the other. If the type is over-represented in data set 1 relative to data set 2, then the same type is under-represented in data set 2 relative to data set 1. You could compute proportions by column and compute the differences between data set 1 and 2 for each row. But your sample size is so large that many of the types will be statistically different. Also you would be making 300 comparisons which creates multiple comparison issues.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to make a contingency table for each material type, considering 2 cases: the material type under question is either present or absent. You can get a p value for such a table using either chi square or a Fisher exact test. You may want to adjust p values for multiple testing. Here is an example of doing a Fisher exact test for material of type 1:

```
data = data.frame(
    Material.Type = c("type 1","type 2","type 3","type 300"),
    Data.set.1 = c(534,0,2276,400),
    Data.set.2 = c(22,25,9875,137),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

total = apply(data[,c(2,3)], 2, sum)

## Fisher exact test for material type 1
type = "type 1"
pos = data[data$Material.Type == type, c(2,3)]
neg = total - pos
tbl = rbind(pos, neg)
rownames(tbl) = c(type, "other")
print(tbl)
fisher.test(tbl)
```